# Pandas HDFStore retrieving data preformance understanding

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, hdfstore

So at first it was like I encounter on another bug, but in the end of all tests I become pretty unsure that it's really a bug and that I understand how to build data processing pipeline with pandas HDF.

Take a sit, let's ride together. Hope you may clarify for me something in the end.

---

---

Preparing

```py
SIZE_0 = 10**6
SIZE_1 = 4
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(SIZE_0, SIZE_1))
print (df.head())
```

```py
          0         1         2         3
0  0.327362  0.084638  0.124322  0.116745
1  0.606545  0.484079  0.977239  0.120613
2  0.014407  0.973912  0.464409  0.959907
3  0.357551  0.641503  0.889408  0.776769
4  0.770845  0.548562  0.587054  0.569719
```

Put to store into 2 parts

```py
cols1 = list(df.columns[:SIZE_1//2])
cols2 = list(df.columns[SIZE_1//2:])
with pd.HDFStore('test.h5') as store:
    store.put('df1', df[cols1], 't')
    store.put('df2', df[cols2], 't')
```

---

---

Now to the problem. Reading whole df from `HDFStore` with `select_as_multiple` is **much** more slower than `select`:

```py
%%time
with pd.HDFStore('test.h5') as store:
    out = store.select_as_multiple(['df1', 'df2'])
print (out.shape)
```

```py
(1000000, 4)
CPU times: user 24.3 s, sys: 38.6 ms, total: 24.3 s
Wall time: 24.3 s
```

And plain `select`:

```py
%%time
with pd.HDFStore('test.h5') as store:
    df1 = store.select('df1')
    df2 = store.select('df2')
    out = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print (out.shape)
```

```py
(1000000, 4)
CPU times: user 48.1 ms, sys: 23.9 ms, total: 72 ms
Wall time: 68.3 ms
```

So at this point i was going to post it as performance issue, but after some initial 'dumb-checking' (as i thought it was) I receive surprising (at least for me) results.

---

---

Let's increase number of columns and see what will happen.

```py
SIZE_1 = 8
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(SIZE_0, SIZE_1))

cols1 = list(df.columns[:SIZE_1//2])
cols2 = list(df.columns[SIZE_1//2:])
with pd.HDFStore('test.h5') as store:
    store.put('df1', df[cols1], 't')
    store.put('df2', df[cols2], 't')
```

Now using same code for `select_as_multiple` we will get output:

```py
(1000000, 8)
CPU times: user 14.7 s, sys: 87.3 ms, total: 14.8 s
Wall time: 14.8 s
```

*Strange* things. We increased our data size twice but wall time now is `10s` lower.

At the same time code for retrieve df by `select` executes a bit slower:

```py
(1000000, 8)
CPU times: user 90.6 ms, sys: 27.9 ms, total: 119 ms
Wall time: 115 ms
```

---

---

Well after that I was unable to stop my curiosity and make it another test shot :). Now with instantiating df by `SIZE_1 = 16` (again all other rows of code are unchanged - won't copy them here again for brevity sake).

Now `select_as_multiple` runs even ***faster***:

```py
(1000000, 16)
CPU times: user 8.27 s, sys: 184 ms, total: 8.45 s
Wall time: 8.45 s
```

But for plain `select` everything is as expected - execution time increased:

```py
(1000000, 16)
CPU times: user 181 ms, sys: 124 ms, total: 306 ms
Wall time: 302 ms
```

But at the same time `select` still works much-much faster.

---

---

### Finally to the questions:

#### 1. Why `select_as_multiple` works so poorly comparing with `select`?

BTW, this is not only the problem for selection without specifying `where` condition:

```py
%%time
with pd.HDFStore('test.h5') as store:
    out = store.select_as_multiple(['df1', 'df2'], where='index < 500000')
print (out.shape)
```

```py
(500000, 16)
CPU times: user 4.65 s, sys: 56.7 ms, total: 4.7 s
Wall time: 4.69 s
```

And for `select`:

```py
%%time
with pd.HDFStore('test.h5') as store:
    df1 = store.select('df1', where='index < 500000')
    df2 = store.select('df2', where='index < 500000')
    out = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print (out.shape)
```

```py
(500000, 16)
CPU times: user 871 ms, sys: 89 ms, total: 960 ms
The decreasing of time (with such particular `where`) should be more expected, since we have to 
Wall time: 927 ms
```

Still much faster. But one may **note**, that `where` *reduces* time for `select_as_multiple` and at the same time *increases* it for `select`. So here is another question:

---

#### 2. Why specifying `where` clause _reduces_ time for `select_as_multiple` and at the same time _increases_ it for `select`?

The expected behavior is both increasing or both decreasing for particular `where`. But not opposite to each other.

---

#### 3. Why increasing data size in axis=1 direction decreases read time for `select_as_multiple`?

We are increasing data size but selection performs almost multiple times faster? That's strange. Maybe this is design 'feature' that says - *Don't use HDF storage until you have **really** big column count in your df*? But I couldn't recall something like that from [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#hdf5-pytables). Only opposite use cases - exactly in section with [`select_as_multiple`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#multiple-table-queries) that suggests to split your data into 'query' columns and 'others' (so decrease column count in stored dfs) in order to speed up queries.

---

Let's do some *more* tests.

`SIZE_0 = 10**6` and `SIZE_1 = 16`:

```py
%%time
with pd.HDFStore('test.h5') as store:
    out = store.select_as_multiple(['df1', 'df2'])
print (out.shape)
```

```py
(1000000, 16)
CPU times: user 8.39 s, sys: 232 ms, total: 8.62 s
Wall time: 8.64 s
```

Increasing df size in **axis=0** twice `SIZE_0 = 2*10**6` and `SIZE_1 = 16`:

```py
%%time
with pd.HDFStore('test.h5') as store:
    out = store.select_as_multiple(['df1', 'df2'])
print (out.shape)
```

```py
(2000000, 16)
CPU times: user 32.3 s, sys: 370 ms, total: 32.6 s
Wall time: 32.6 s
```

Versus increasing df size in **axis=1** twice `SIZE_0 = 10**6` and `SIZE_1 = 2*16`:

```py
%%time
with pd.HDFStore('test.h5') as store:
    out = store.select_as_multiple(['df1', 'df2'])
print (out.shape)
```

```py
(1000000, 32)
CPU times: user 9.05 s, sys: 384 ms, total: 9.43 s
Wall time: 9.43 s
```

So `32s v 10s`.

#### 4. This means that for HDF storing it is much more efficient appending columns instead of rows?!

That is really confusing. Isn't it wrong? As far as I understand `PyTables` same as `pandas HDF` is 'row oriented'?

---

One may have notice from latter test that we finally get execution time increased after expand our data in `axis=1` direction. Let's find out when exactly it has started to be true:

```py
SIZE_0 = 10**6
SIZE_1s = list(range(4, 40)) # List of SIZE_1 to iterate

# Iterating
timings = []
for SIZE_1 in SIZE_1s:
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(SIZE_0, SIZE_1))

    cols1 = list(df.columns[:SIZE_1//2])
    cols2 = list(df.columns[SIZE_1//2:])
    with pd.HDFStore('test.h5') as store:
        # Put to store
        store.put('df1', df[cols1], 't')
        store.put('df2', df[cols2], 't')
        # Read from store, note the time
        start = pd.Timestamp.now()
        out = store.select_as_multiple(['df1', 'df2'])
        # Appending timings
        timings.append((pd.Timestamp.now()-start).total_seconds())
# Plotting
to_plot = pd.DataFrame(timings,
                       index=pd.Index(SIZE_1s, name='column_C'),
                       columns=['read time'])
_ = to_plot.plot(figsize = (14, 6),
                 title = 'DF read time from HDF store by DFs column count',
                 color = 'blue')
```

[image: OUTPUT]

So initial dynamic (up to 23-24 columns) is straightforward - more columns = faster reading.

#### 5. Is 24 columns count (we should divide here for 2 df, i.e. about 12 columns) something like design threshold? And only after reaching it one should think about using HDF store?

---

---

Some system info:

```py
pd.__version__
tables.__version__
```

```py
'0.24.2'
'3.5.1'
```

Also has `24GB` install on 64-bit Ubuntu 19.04. And at the same time largest of used dfs in tests was about `300MB` size. So it shouldn't have made any problem.

**EDIT:** since no explanation were given - I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26771).